# Djangoでpickleを読み込む時のエラー

Tags: python, django

Djangoでアプリを作っている時のエラーです。
まず、Djagoとは別のレポジトリであるクラスを作成し、そのインスタンスをpickle形式で保存しました。
そして、Djangoのapp/views.pyでそのクラスをインポートし、さらにpickleデータをloadしようとしました。すると、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
% python manage.py runserver                                                               
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.        
<locals>.wrapper at 0x1058489d8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/you_mac/.pyenv/versions/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

・・・

  File "/Users/you_mac/workspace/python/django-app/django-
app/classifier/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/you_mac/workspace/python/django-app/django-
app/classifier/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    obj = pickle.load(f)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'NaiveBayes' on <module '__main__' from 'manage.py'>
```

ディレクトリの構造はこのようになっています(抽象化しています)。

```
- django/
    - django-app/
        - mysite/
        - manage.py
        - app/
            - templates/
            - urls.py
            - views.py
    - src/
        - src1.py
        - model.pkl
```

django/src/src1.pyのコードです（わかりやすいようにかなり省略してます）。

```
import pickle

class NaiveBayes:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.dic = {}
    def train(self):
        for d in self.data:
            self.dic[d] += 1
    def classify(self, text):
        """辞書を使ってスコアを計算し、クラス分類"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = ["a", "b", ...]
    cls = NaiveBayes(data)

    with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(cls, f)
```

django/django-app/app/views.pyです（かなり省略）。

```
import pickle, sys, os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".") + '/../src')
from src1 import NaiveBayes

path = os.path.abspath("../src")
with open(path+'/model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
obj.train()

def form(request):
    category = obj.classify(request.POST['text'])

    ・・・
```

ざっくりした説明ですが、解決方法がありましたらご教授ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずこれで動くであろう修正点を記載します。

django/src/src1.py の NaiveBayes を 別モジュール(例えばbayes.pyとか作って) に移動してimportする

```
import pickle

from bayes import NaiveBayes # <- 移動した モジュールからimport


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = ["a", "b", ...]
    cls = NaiveBayes(data)

    with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(cls, f)
```

django/django-app/app/views.py では NavieBayes importしなくて良い

```
import pickle, sys, os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".") + '/../src')

# delete this line.
# from src1 import NaiveBayes # <- importしなくても良い、上でパスを通すだけで良い。

path = os.path.abspath("../src")
with open(path+'/model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
obj.train()

def form(request):
    category = obj.classify(request.POST['text'])
```

ここまでの修正で、上記エラーは解消されるはずです。次になぜこうなるのか説明します。

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'NaiveBayes' on <module '__main__' from 'manage.py'>
```

`__main__` モジュール に `NaiveBayes` がないというエラーになっています。

これは `python src1.py` と実行した時にに `__main__.NaiveBayes` というクラスをPickle化して保存してしまったからです。

[https://docs.python.jp/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/__main__.html)

ドキュメントにもある通り、 python コマンドで渡した scriptファイルはどんなファイル名であっても `__main__` モジュールとして扱われます。それは `python manage.py` でも一緒です。

なので

```
1. python src1.py で `__main__.NavieBayes` を Pickle化保存
2. python mange.py runserver で 1のpikcle から `__main__.NavieBayes` 
   を loadしようとしたけど、実際に存在してるのは `src1.NaiveBayes`なのでエラーとなる。
```

そこで敢えて別モジュール `bayes` を作りその中に NaiveBayes を 移動することで、両方とも `bayes.NaiveBayes` を参照するようにすれば今回のエラーが回避できます。

```
1. python src1.py で `bayes.NavieBayes` を Pickle化保存
2. python mange.py runserver で 1のpikcle から `bayes.NavieBayes` を loadする
```

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます！解決しました。Pickle化する際の__name__と非Pickle化する際の__name__の状態を考慮する必要があるのですね。とてもわかりやすい説明ありがとうございました。